# You have an error in your SQL syntax - but everything seems fine

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I'm still learning php and every issue seems even more misleading when I try to look for an answer since everyone gives other method. I've seen many questions like this, but I've used pretty much every reasonable part of answers I can use in my issue.

What Im doing is in my game site Im sending quest data - it's ID (integer) and point value (also integer) from a form using ajax. Both console log before sending and echo after sending show proper values, e.g. questID=1&questPTS=5 and in php 1 and 5 respectively.

**What Im trying to do is update quest status on users profile in the database.
Table is called "profiles", but quests are columns with names from 1 to 25 (numbers).** So Im doing an update in table profiles to set specific quest (in this example "1") to 1 (from current 0 to 1, which I treat then as my status) where users "id" is the id stored in session.

I was struggling with using variables in mysql request as I dont know this language. After executing the code I get an error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1=1 WHERE id=60' at line 1 in >php file path here< on line 12*

Looks like variables are working fine, because clicked quest is indeed 1 and user id stored in session is 60. I've seen many answers like putting number names of columns in back ticks like '$questID' (I don't really know how to input them here), separating variables with dots etc but no difference, changing integer/string in bind param also does nothing.

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_connect.php';
$questID = $_POST['questID'];
$questID = strval($questID); //this gives 1 in this example
$questPTS = '';
$id = $_SESSION['id']; //this gives 60 in this example
if (isset($_POST['questID'])){
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE profiles SET $questID=1 WHERE id=$id");
    if ($statement === false) {
      trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
      return;
    }
    $questPTS = $_POST['questPTS'];
    $statement->bind_param('si', $questID, $id);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)){
        echo "Updated";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: $sql. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
    $statement->close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your problem is that you are putting the value of `$questID` into your query where you should be putting the field name. Try `UPDATE profiles SET questID= $questID WHERE id=$id`, assuming your table has a field of this name.

Comment: Just to check - do you really have columns called '1', and if this is the question number, then you need to look into normalising the table structure rather than sorting this problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query evaluates to:

```
UPDATE profiles SET 1=1 WHERE id=60
```

That is indeed a SQL syntax error. Numeric column names **must** be escaped in backticks, so you should be aiming for this:

```
UPDATE profiles SET `1`=1 WHERE id=60
```

Quick note: you cannot use a parameter for a column identifier, and since your column name is coming from user input you need to take some extra care to prevent SQL injection. You *can* use a parameter for the `$id` value, which you are currently not doing correctly.

```
// first, make sure `$questID` is actually a number (this will make it 0 if a
// user is testing your security with a string value)
$questID = (int)$questID;

// use an actual placeholder for the $id value
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE profiles SET `$questID`=1 WHERE id=?");

// Only $id needs to be bound, because $questID is not a parameter
$statement->bind_param('i', $id);
```

Comment: that did it! thank you very much, didn't know that each thing in bind param is actually not everything I dont currently know, but the thing that actually changes in database, very usefull for me! I agree with security thing, but here its not a priority, its a project of a game for single party Im hosting today :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your update statement to the following. May be you just need to use backticks around your column name.

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE profiles SET `$questID` =1 WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: it isnt a column, column names are numbers 1 to 25 (there are 25 quests) so I must use a variable to give number based on quest clicked on site, thats my biggest problem that the column is changing, not the value I want to set

Comment: @Assaeyedjames I changed my answer, please see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has no placeholder (?)

```
UPDATE profiles SET questID= ?  WHERE id= ?
```

And you mixed up procedural with object oriented. Simply remove it

```
if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)){
        echo "Updated";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: $sql. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
```

Comment: can I use ? as column name? thats my biggest problem here, that the column is variable, and the value I set is always the same